# Why can't I call Global.alloc_zeroed()

Tags: rust

The type `std::alloc::Global` is supposed to have the `AllocRef` trait, which has `alloc_zeroed`(layout) pub method. But I can't use it .... I ran "rustup override add nightly"  to use a nightly. It seems that `AllocRef` trait is not available in here but I don't know how to make it visible... Please help!

Thank you! I ran "rustup override set nightly" but "rustup show" output did not change and it still failed to compile.. Added "rustup show" output at the end.

PS.
After running "rustup override set nightly-2020-01-09-x86_64-apple-darwin" and adding "use std::alloc::Alloc", I see it got compiled! When I ran "rustup override set nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin", it did not compile..

My code:

```
#![feature(allocator_api)]
use std::alloc::{Layout,Global,Alloc};  // added "Alloc"
fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let layout = Layout::new::<i32>();
        println!("{:?}", Global.alloc_zeroed(layout));
    }
}
```

Compile error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `alloc_zeroed` found for struct `std::alloc::Global` in the 
current scope
 --> src/main.rs:6:26
  |
6 |     println!("{:?}", Global.alloc_zeroed(layout));
  |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `std::alloc::Global`
error: aborting due to previous error
```

rustup show:

```
Default host: x86_64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/user1/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-2020-01-09-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin (directory override for '/Users/user1/as/rust22')
rustc 1.51.0-nightly (1d0d76f8d 2021-01-24)
```

Comment: What does `rustup show` give you?

Comment: Can you run `rustup override set nightly`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Alloc` trait have been renamed `Allocator` & `alloc_zeroed` have been renamed `allocate_zeroed`.

[Link to nightly docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/alloc/trait.Allocator.html)

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9969fdb5568caf67c769e69930b5e12d)

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you are still on the stable toolchain. `rustup override add nightly` doesn't switch to nightly it just installs it. Run `rustup override set nightly` to switch to the nightly toolchain. Then run `rustup show` to see what your current toolchain is.